# Clarification on understanding the node and edge index

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-geometric

By accessing the `data` object's properties,
how would I know which node feature belongs to what node?
If I understand it correctly `data.x` holds the node features.
By running for loop below I can access the features
but how would I know that if it belongs to node 0 or node 9 for an example?
​

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data
edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 9],
                           [1, 0, 2, 1, 8, 1]
                           ], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.tensor([[-5,7], [0,5], [0,9], [10,9]], dtype=torch.float)
​
data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index)
​
for item in range(0, data.x.shape[0]):
    print(item, data.x[item], data.edge_index.t()[item])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, by defining `x` as you have, Pytorch Geometric infers (from the shape of `x`) that four nodes exist. This is specified in the [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data.html#torch_geometric.data.Dataset):

> The number of nodes in the data object is automatically inferred in case node-level attributes are present, e.g., `data.x`.

You have also specified edges for nodes up to node 9. If you try to run any models on this code, I suspect it would produce an error as there are only four nodes expected to be present. This is because it will try to access the 9th element of `x` which will return an index error.

The best practice is to define the number of nodes present. As stated in the [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data.html#torch_geometric.data.Dataset):

> we recommend to set the number of nodes in your data object explicitly via `data.num_nodes = ...